# doctrine 2 how to select specific result from a many to many association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm facing a problem with doctrine 2. I have two entities Catalogs and Category joined by an unidirectionnal many to many association, a catalog belongs to many category, I want to select catalogs belonging to a given category.

Example:
I have a given category `$category`

```
$qb->select('cat')
   ->from('Catalog', 'cat')
   ->where($category in cat.categories)   
//I know it is wrong just to explain
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I want to know how to select  catalogs which have a given category in their category list